# Apache Kafka: how to configure message buffering properly

Tags: apache-kafka

I run a system comprising an InfluxDB, a Kafka Broker and data sources (sensors) producing time series data. The purpose of the broker is to protect the database from inbound event overload and as a format-agnostic platform for ingesting data. The data is transferred from Kafka to InfluxDB via Apache Camel routes.
I would like to use Kafka a intermediate message buffer in case a Camel route crashes or becomes unavailable - which is the most often error in the system. Up to now, I didn’t achieve to configure Kafka in a manner that inbound messages remain available for later consumption.
How do I configure it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages will retain in Kafka topics based on its *retention* policies (you can choose between time or byte size limits) as described in the [Topic Configurations](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html). With

```
cleanup.policy=delete
Retention.ms=-1
```

the messages will in a Kafka topic will never be deleted.

Then your camel consumer will be able to re-read all messages (offsets) if you select a new consumer group or reset the offsets of the existing consumer group. Otherwise, your camel consumer might auto commit the messages (check corresponding consumer configuration) and it will not be possible to re-read offsets again for the same consumer group.

To limit the consumption rate of the camel consumer you may adjust configurations like `maxPollRecords` or `fetchMaxBytes` which are described in the [docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/kafka-component.html).